# What doe IPO and FPO mean? Are they related to Equity services?

Tags: investing, financial-literacy, terminology, ipo

Are the terms 'IPO' and 'FPO' related to equity? If so, how? Are they related to any kind of investments?

Answer (score 5):

IPO Means Initial Public Offer: This is the first time a Private company issues shares to the Public at large. The shares could be new shares created or part sell of by Original Owners, or a combination of both.

FPO Means Follow on Public Offer: Additional shares offered to Public by the company. Typically new shares are created and funds raised.